# Binding when using XPath and UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, binding, xpath

I'm binding text boxes to XML data using the XPath and UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit. This works perfect when the XPath-statement is simple such as:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding XPath=Length, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

The correct value from the XML data is displayed in the TextBox. Since I don't want the changes in the TextBox to be synchronized with the XML data instantly I use the explicit UpdateSourceTrigger and an "Apply"-button. When clicking the button the following code is executed:

```
BindingExpression be = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
be.UpdateSource();
```

"tb" is the TextBox (I'm looping a list of text boxes).

This all works well. The problem is when the XPath is a bit more complex. I have XML data that looks like this:

```
<Tags>
  <Tag TagType="1">
    <Name>122</Name>
    <Offset>1212</Offset>
  </Tag>
  <Tag TagType="2">
    <Name />
    <Offset />
  </Tag>
</Tags>
```

To bind a TextBox with the first Tag the XPath statement looks like this

```
XPath='Tags/Tag[@TagType=1]/Name'
```

The strange part is now that the TextBox is filled with the value "122" but it's not possible to update the value. When clicking the apply button that value is not "saved back" into the XML data. But, if I remove the UpdateSourceTrigger option from the binding then is data saved to the XML. However, then is data continuously updated, which is not what I want.

Why doesn't UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit work when XPath is more complex than a single element name? Any ideas how I can fix this?

Regards,
Patrick